# C++ C2065 Variables in .h not accessible from .cpp file

Tags: c++

Green coder here working on first C++ assignment and I'm seeking help on where I've gone wrong. Googled this error/situation and haven't found something close enough here to find the solution.

The assignment is to create a date class and then test it with a provided .cpp file. I wrote the whole thing out and compiled and got a depressing number of errors, so commented out much of it to debug the core first and I'm down to errors essentially saying the date.cpp can't find the variables defined in date.h. Googling seems to indicate that it's an include error but I have date.h included.

At one point, I had date.h defining month, day, year before capitalizing them, and the IDE (VS 2019 Community) suggested including  (may have this misspelled) so I capitalized the variable names.

Thanks in advance for the help. I'm assuming (hoping?) I've got a conceptual issue here that's easy to tidy up.

```
// Program Name: date.h
#include <string>

#ifndef DATE_H
    #define DATE_H
#endif

// Start of class

class Date {

public: 
    explicit Date(unsigned int = 1, unsigned int = 1, unsigned int = 2000); // default ctor setting to 1/1/2000 per specs
    std::string tointString() const; // date string in month/day/year format
    std::string toFullString() const; // date string in date fullMonth year format
    ~Date(); // Gotta have the dtor

    // get functions
    unsigned int getMonth();
    unsigned int getDay();
    unsigned int getYear();

    std::string getMonthName() const;

private: // Core date data   Book seems to want to use unsigned. Does this force non-negagive #s?

    unsigned int Month; // month of year 1-12
    unsigned int Day; // day of month 1-31 (leap year adjustments not required in this assignment)
    unsigned int Year; // Will be using 1900 as the minimum year.

    unsigned int checkDate(int, int); // Function to validate the days in a month

}; // end of Date
```

Here's date.cpp which is where the errors occur. The errors are in the three 'get' functions at the end.
**date.cpp(47,34): error C2065: 'Month': undeclared identifier**

```
// 
// Program Name; date.cpp
// Assignment: Date object assignment
//

#include "date.h" // class include file
#include <iostream> // standard output
#include <sstream> // formatted output
#include <string> // work with strings
#include <array> // needed for various arrays in get functions

using namespace std; // save all the scope fun

unsigned int const monthsInYear{ 12 }; // var just to make code more readable.

// Parameter based constructor w/ value checks
//
Date::Date(unsigned int mon, unsigned int dy, unsigned int yr) 
// initialization list and start of value checking  
    : Month{ mon }, Day{ checkDate(dy , mon ) }, Year{ yr } { 
    if (mon < 1 || mon > monthsInYear) {
        Month = 1; // if month out of range, set to 1 per specs
    } // end of month value check if
    if (yr < 1900 || yr > 2100) { // arbitrary upper limit
        Year = 1900;
    } // end of year value check if

} // end initialization list

int checkDate(unsigned int dayToCheck , unsigned int mon ) {
    static array <unsigned int, monthsInYear> daysInMonth{ 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 }; // Array showing how many days in each month
    unsigned int dayToReturn{ 1 }; // Value to return. Per specs, if dayToCheck is out of range, we will return 1.

    if (dayToCheck >= 1 && dayToCheck <= daysInMonth[mon - 1]) { // needs to be month -1 re: index starts at 0
        dayToReturn = dayToCheck; // dayToCheck inside the proper range, so set dateToReturn to that value.
    } // end if block for day in month range check.

    return dayToReturn; // returning the value.

} // end of dateCheck

// Functions for retrieving data
//
unsigned int getMonth() { return Month; }
unsigned int getDay() { return Day; }
unsigned int getYear() { return Year; }
```

Comment: You missed to specify the scope `Date::` in the other function definitions.

Comment: unsigned int Date::getMonth() { return Month; }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C2065 undeclared identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022743/c2065-undeclared-identifier)

Comment: `#ifndef DATE_H
    #define DATE_H
#endif` is not correct for an include guard, btw.

Answer (score 4):

As you've written them `getMonth` and the other functions in that .cpp file are just standalone functions that have no relation to `Date`.

You need to write `unsigned int Date::getMonth()` and similarly for the others to express that they're part of `Date`

Comment: Thank you.  I had actually used "Date::" in previous debugging attempts and it didn't resolve. I am guessing that additional debugging efforts after the last time I'd tried that allowed this to now do its job.

No more errors in the code, just linker errors now. Back at it. Thanks again!

1>date.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: unsigned int __thiscall Date::checkDate(int,int)"  referenced in function "public: __thiscall Date::Date(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)

 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Date::~Date(void)"  in function _main